# Copy survey in text file and paste in my application

Tags: ios, copy-paste

I am doing one IOS native app in swift. I want to copy text data and parse it to paste into table view. I am not able to find the right way to do it.

Comment: what have you tried, what is the exact input + expected output / result?

Comment: When I copy text data and try to parse in my app, it is showing nothing.

Comment: follow this link may it help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188852/copy-paste-text-into-ios-simulator

Comment: Why do you expect anything else to happen, what do you expect to happen, what have you currently written that makes you expect anything else?

Comment: I have a text file like
0.00     0.00    0.00
12.23   34.21  98.32
----
After parsing, I need to show these values in my table view.

Comment: load this text file in a string and split this string by space and then you'll get array of number string and then load your table view

Comment: I am still not able to parse with space as it is tab space between each value. How can I split with tab space?